# Action of the Liouvillian in Koopman-von Neumann Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, operators, fourier-transform

I am trying to calculate the effect of the KvN Liouvillian operator but am getting a bit stuck. As it is the generator of time translations in KvN mechanics, and since in classical mechanics a point in phase space remains a single point,

$$\delta(x-x_0, p-p_0) \overset{L}{\longrightarrow} \delta(x-x_1, p-p_1),$$

I would expect a result of the form:

$$L|x_0,p_0\rangle = a|x_1,p_1\rangle$$

for some constant $a$.

The KvN form of $L$ is:

$$L = \frac{P \Lambda_{x}}{m} - \nabla U(X) \Lambda_{p},$$

where capitals are operators and $\Lambda_{x}$ and $\Lambda_{p}$ are the canonical conjugates to $X$ and $P$. Applying this to a joint position-momentum eigenstate $|x_0,p_0\rangle$ gives

$$L|x_0,p_0\rangle = \frac{p_0}{m} \Lambda_{x}|x_0,p_0\rangle - \nabla U(x_0) \Lambda_{p}|x_0,p_0\rangle.$$

Based on the canonical relationship, it is clear that a joint eigenstate of $\Lambda_{x}$ and $\Lambda_{p}$, $|k_{x_0},k_{p_0}\rangle$, can be expressed as

$$|k_{x_0},k_{p_0}\rangle = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}p}{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{ik_{x_0}x}\mathrm{e}^{ik_{p_0}p}|x,p\rangle.$$

Hence (by inverting the Fourier transform) I manage to get:

$$L|x_0,p_0\rangle = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}k_x\mathrm{d}k_p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{p_0}{m}k_x - \nabla U(x_0)k_p\right)\mathrm{e}^{-ik_{x}x_0}\mathrm{e}^{-ik_{p}p_0}|k_x,k_p\rangle$$

But now I'm stumped. As I said, I feel like it should be possible to write this out in the form

$$L|x_0,p_0\rangle = a\int\frac{\mathrm{d}k_x\mathrm{d}k_p}{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-ik_{x}x_1}\mathrm{e}^{-ik_{p}p_1}|k_x,k_p\rangle = a|x_1,p_1\rangle$$

for some $x_1$ and $p_1$ but can't see a way forward.